# RAD: Dependency Injection - benefits?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, dependency-injection, rad

Are there any benefits of using dependency injection at all when using RAD - or not using unit testing in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeh there are several benefits as follows:

1. Reduced Dependencies
2. Reduced Dependency Carrying
3. More Reusable Code
4. More Testable Code
5. More Readable Code

For more reference [click here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/dependency-injection/dependency-injection-benefits.html)